# POSIXct Equality Working Oddly

Tags: r, posixct

I'm reading in a CSV into a variable "stuff" and coercing the first column to POSIXct (this column only has timestamps, of the form "2012-12-04 17:49:52", so this works well).

```
stuff[,1]<-as.POSIXct(stuff[,1])
```

Since I have several days' worth of data, I'm then trying to break things up by date:

```
control <- subset(stuff,as.Date(stuff[,1]) == '2012-11-27')
control.1 <- subset(stuff,as.Date(stuff[,1]) == '2012-11-28')
```

I find that this doesn't split the data up by dates as I would expect. 
tail(control) shows me that the last value is at 2012-11-27 15:54:21, while head(control.1) shows that its first value is 2012-11-27 16:04:35.

The equality therefore seems to pivot somewhere around 16:00 for some reason. I tried specifying timezones when coercing to POSIXct, but this didn't help either. Is there anything I can do to subset by day (and is there a reason this failed)? I'd like to mention that I need to keep the hourly information in there, since I plan on using it to slice up the data subsequently.

Comment: It is because of time zones. You can specify timezone in as.Date, by default it is UTC so when you convert your time stamps to dates, some will fall on different date. Make sure your time zone in as.Date matches to your time stamp time zone

Comment: I tried fixing timestamps saying `stuff[,1] <- as.Date(stuff[,1],tzone="PST")`, and specifying timezones in the equality check as well, but I got the same results.
The interesting thing is I get the right result if I do:
`control <- subset(cases,cases[,1] <= as.POSIXct('2012-11-27 23:59:59'))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps `cut` might be of use to you, but it is hard to tell for sure without a sample of your data that replicates the problem you're having.

Here's a minimal example of using `cut` to create your daily subsets.

```
set.seed(1) # So you can get the same numbers as I do
MyDates <- ISOdatetime(2012, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, tz = "GMT") + sample(1:500000, 100)
class(MyDates)
# [1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 
split(MyDates, cut(MyDates, breaks="1 day"))
$`2012-01-01`
 [1] "2012-01-01 08:34:53 GMT" "2012-01-01 17:26:15 GMT" "2012-01-01 01:51:35 GMT"
 [4] "2012-01-01 14:59:28 GMT" "2012-01-01 03:14:25 GMT" "2012-01-01 09:48:56 GMT"
 [7] "2012-01-01 13:48:48 GMT" "2012-01-01 11:41:58 GMT" "2012-01-01 16:53:56 GMT"
[10] "2012-01-01 19:54:00 GMT" "2012-01-01 08:11:02 GMT"

$`2012-01-02`
 [1] "2012-01-02 12:52:35 GMT" "2012-01-02 04:00:41 GMT" "2012-01-02 04:36:26 GMT"
 [4] "2012-01-02 00:31:17 GMT" "2012-01-02 05:27:47 GMT" "2012-01-02 13:06:44 GMT"
 [7] "2012-01-02 23:16:05 GMT" "2012-01-02 01:51:43 GMT" "2012-01-02 09:59:46 GMT"
::::
::::
::::
[13] "2012-01-05 10:25:04 GMT" "2012-01-05 20:34:21 GMT" "2012-01-05 11:56:40 GMT"
[16] "2012-01-05 02:56:40 GMT" "2012-01-05 09:08:00 GMT" "2012-01-05 02:45:00 GMT"
[19] "2012-01-05 12:09:45 GMT" "2012-01-05 14:42:59 GMT" "2012-01-05 16:35:56 GMT"

$`2012-01-06`
 [1] "2012-01-06 06:08:22 GMT" "2012-01-06 04:46:31 GMT" "2012-01-06 11:12:12 GMT"
 [4] "2012-01-06 17:45:37 GMT" "2012-01-06 09:48:54 GMT" "2012-01-06 00:47:02 GMT"
 [7] "2012-01-06 06:46:24 GMT" "2012-01-06 01:33:21 GMT" "2012-01-06 03:53:53 GMT"
[10] "2012-01-06 00:01:45 GMT" "2012-01-06 13:23:54 GMT" "2012-01-06 01:40:54 GMT"
```